# How to use filter for ng-repeat loop in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm working on an ng-repeat that it will fill a div from a collction o object I have field called videos.description in those object with a large value so i want to change his value to a short value using filter this my code  :

```
<div class="panel panel-default videoPanel" ng-repeat="video in videos.data | shortDescription :'video.description'">
    <h6 style="text-align: center">{{video.name}}</h6>
    <div class="panel-body" style="margin-top:-50px;">
        <video width="100%" height="190" controls style="margin:auto">
            <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <input id="input-7-xs" class="rating rating-loading" value="1" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.5" data-size="xs">
        <p>{{video.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this my filter :

```
app.filter('shortDescription', function() {
  return function(items, field) {
        var result = [];
        length=40;
        angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
            items[key].value=value.description.substring(0, length);
            console.log(field);
            result.push(items[key]);
        });
        return result;
    };
});
```

using this filter I still have a large value in the field description can someone help me thanks in advance

Comment: You could consider leaving the description as is, and provide for a style setting [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp). Might make it lots easier when you want to have a click handler at a later time (no need to research the original description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
items[key].value=value.description.substring(0, length);
```

You have to update the `description`:

```
items[key].description=value.description.substring(0, length);
```

For this functionality, you can use `map` method, which accepts a `callback` function.

```
return items.map(function(item){
   return {"name":item.name,"description":item.description.substring(0,length)};
});
```